# Is there quick way to find static variables in Java in Netbeans to decrease initial memory?

Tags: java, memory, netbeans, static

SITUATION:
Hello; for years in all my projects,
I have been using static variables, to make codes talk with each other.

CONDITION:
I am specifically using Netbeans. But you can share other IDE solutions so people can see.

QUESTION:
Is there any way to find them all?
So, I can turn them into functions, to decrease some initial memory.

Comment: There's always *grep* ...

Comment: Re _"could you also share details on how to use it."_, this is not a help forum, and that question is off topic here. You are expected to have made some effort and done some research before asking questions here. That said, if you had attempted to actually use **Source->Inspect** you would have found out that it doesn't work! See NetBeans Issue [NETBEANS-6388 Source->Inspect no longer works](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-6388)

Comment: Use a profiler to see which globals use most memory.

Comment: @skomisa Noted; remarks removed.

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen :  My question is about changing the style of many already written project libraries.

Comment: @tulga unclear wording then.  What characterize the things you look for, that separates them for all the other things you don’t look for?

Comment: What makes you think that turning static variables into functions will save memory? Please provide an example of what you're talking about.

Comment: "if u create a global static variable, it will never be garbage collected. Hovever if you put it inside a function, it will be." is what i thought. Ofcourse It will runs slower. For ram crippled machines like web servers it is matter of tunning, there is no right choice.

Answer (score 0):

I couldnot find an IDE solution to help coders. So, I came up with my own answer.

- I recursively find all java files
- read them as lines
- selectively log them to a text file

Here is an example:

```
package com.tugalsan.tryout5;

import com.tugalsan.api.file.server.*;
import com.tugalsan.api.file.txt.server.*;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.util.stream.*;

public class Run {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        var parentDirectory = Path.of("C:\\me\\codes\\GWT");
        var results = parentDirectory.resolve("results.log");
        TS_FileUtils.deleteFileIfExists(results);
        var append = true;
        var fileNameMatcher = "*.java";
        var sorted = false;
        var recursive = true;
        TS_DirectoryUtils.subFiles(parentDirectory, fileNameMatcher, sorted, recursive).forEach(javaFile -> {
            var lines = TS_FileTXTUtils.toArrayList(javaFile);
            IntStream.range(0, lines.size())
                    .filter(idx -> lines.get(idx).contains("static"))
                    .filter(idx -> !lines.get(idx).contains("import"))
                    .filter(idx -> !lines.get(idx).contains("class"))
                    .filter(idx -> !lines.get(idx).contains("interface"))
                    .filter(idx -> !lines.get(idx).contains("("))
                    .forEach(idx -> {
                        var line = lines.get(idx);
                        var logLine = String.join("", javaFile.toString(), ", ", String.valueOf(idx), ", ", line, "\n");
                        TS_FileTXTUtils.toFile(logLine, results, append);
                    });
        });
    }
}
```

full code at [github](https://github.com/tugalsan/com.tugalsan.trm.findstaticglobals)